# Is there a log kept of when a parental control time limit extension is granted?

Tags: catalina, mojave, big-sur, parental-controls, screen-time

My kids use a Mac which is running a version of macOS prior to Big Sur (i.e. before the huge redesign of how parental controls work). To limit screen time, they have a set amount of time before "dad has to come in and enter a password".

I suspect one of my kids MIGHT have figured out my password, but I am curious if there is a log file that can be examined to see when any time extensions were granted? Of course, I could just change my password but I'd like to think that one of the system logs would say "1 hour extension granted to  by " with a timestamp.

Is parental controls / screen time "grants" logged? Though my question is Mojave/Catalina primarily, I am interested in Big Sur and later as well.